# When needing to deep clone a single object, should I be worried about the most performant deep cloning algorithm or just make a manual copy?

Tags: c#, deep-copy

There are a lot of options for deep cloning in c# (binary, reflection, expression trees, serialization, etc.). There are also a lot of Q/A about this but they all seem to be fairly old (e.g. pre 2014).

I have a scenario where I need to clone an object to save a modified instance of it, like this...

```
public class Attempt {
  public string Id;
  public DateTime ExpirationDateTime;
  ...
  several other properties that will be the same
}

public Attempt CreateAttemptFromAttempt(Attempt attempt) 
{
  // I could do this
  Attempt cloned = new Attempt() { Id = "aUniqueId", ExpirationDateTime = "new date time" }
  _repository.Save(cloned);
}
```

Given this seemingly simple example, is there a preferred cloning algorithm?  I'd prefer to not manually do this.  I considered using AutoMapper because it's already on the project but have found that even the creator recommends against using it for that.

Comment: If only goal is to save cloned and modified object t the external resource(database), then why you can not just modify `id` and `expirationDate` values on original object and save it.

Comment: That's a good question @Fabio.  I'm very new to c# so if that is acceptable then that sounds like a good solution to me.

Comment: This would be acceptable if original object is not used by something else after or during updating.